# codeigniter: call multiple data in the view

Tags: codeigniter

I can't pass properly multiple data in the view and use it in foreach.

this is my function in controller:

```
 public function pdf() {    

    $this->load->model("model_get");
    $tabela = 'qualities';
    $qualities['qualities'] = $this->model_get->get_data($tabela);
    $tabela = 'language';
    $language['language'] = $this->model_get->get_data($tabela);
    $data = array($qualities, $language);

    $this->load->view('download_pdf', $data);

}
```

and this is my view:

```
<?php
foreach ($qualities as $row) {
    echo $row -> qualities;
}

foreach ($language as $row) {
    echo $row -> language;
    echo $row -> speaking;
    echo $row -> listening;
    echo $row -> reading;
    echo $row -> writing;
}

?>
```

with model everything is fine, and controller is ok too, i gues.

Comment: It's work if I pass just one variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass this `$data` array to the view:

```
$data['qualities'] = $qualities;
$data['language'] = $language;

$this->load->view('download_pdf', $data);
```

Basically you make a [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-83)(An array with a key and a value) where the key of the array is the variable where you call the array in the view. Because when you pass an array to the view it will unfold into variables.

### Example

**Controller:**

```
$data['qualities'] = array( 'key1' => 'test', 'key2' =>'test1');
$data['language'] = array( 'key3' => 'test3', 'key4' =>'test4');
```

Will be unfolded to

**View:**

```
$qualities = array( 'key1' => 'test', 'key2' =>'test1');
$language = array( 'key3' => 'test3', 'key4' =>'test4');
```

---

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: @user3004315 Good :) Glad i could help.